# Convering numbers to their English equivalent?

Tags: dart

Is there a way to format numbers to a text description in Dart? Like `0` would be `'zero'` and `100` would be `'one hundred'`.

Comment: I appreciate that Dart isn't Java, but the same logic applies.

Comment: This is not a dupe. Asking for a Dart-specific package that does this is quite reasonable.